# How to specify earlier Build Tools

Tags: android, android-build

When building from the command line, you usually need to
use an earlier Build Tools, like 18.1.1.

It builds fine when that is the "latest" you have installed,
but if you have 19.1.0 and try to build, even with

```
sdk.buildtools=18.1.1
```

added to your project.properties, it still complains:

```
The SDK Build Tools revision (18.1.1) is too low for project 'Xxx'. Minimum required is 19.1.0
```

Is there any other setting that I can make/change to get it to use 18.1.1 without
uninstalling 19.1.0?

In the main build.xml I see:

```
${android.build.tools.dir}
```

But I can't find where it's defined.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe the build tools is directly tied to the target SDK version. Are you targeting API 19?

Comment: "When building from the command line, you usually need to use an earlier Build Tools, like 18.1.1" -- I have no idea why you think that you "usually" need to do this. I would use "rarely" as the adjective here. You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, explaining what problems you have encountered using newer editions of the build tools on newer projects, and seeking help in overcoming those problems.

Comment: In my project I use: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />   I've built my projects from the command line for a long time, and always got some obscure error that has always been "fixed" by using 18.1.1.  Now I'm really hosed though.  I just uninstalled 19.1.0, re-booted and even ran android update project, and am still getting that error when I try to do an Ant build, but I also updated to Android SDK Tools 23, and SDK Platform-tools 20, could those affect it?

Comment: I should mention that if you look up a lot of those error messages, the remedy that they suggest is going back to an earlier Build Tools.

Comment: I just got the latest Android SDK Tools 23.0.2 and SDK Build Tools 20, and it finally built okay!!  Thank you Google!! :-)

Comment: " 
"When building from the command line, you usually need to use an earlier Build Tools, like 18.1.1" -- I have no idea why you think that you "usually" need to do this" The reason is "reproducible builds". If it worked in a previous version but does not work with latest, then you need to start from your last working version... especially when that version is live and you need to fix an issue there but upgrading to "latest" (or some other version) introduces other issues.

Answer (score 0):

So anyway the answer is -- Android SDK Manager does not install new version of Build Tools but does automatically suggest updating other tools. So when you see above do this:

1. Open "Android SDK Manager".
2. Tick latest version of the "Android SDK Build-tools".
3. Install packages...

And you're done. Build should just work with restart.